# SSRS lookup missing dataset

Tags: reporting-services, lookup, ssrs-2017

I have a dataset which looks like this

```
Name              Spend
"First Aid"       2
"Healing Arts"    0
"Surgeon"         NULL
```

I then have three separate textboxes which will be filled with the value of the column which matches the name.

Example: show value of `spend` in textbox if value of `name` equals `First Aid`
for this I've made following expression

```
=Lookup(Fields!skill_name.Value, "First Aid", Fields!skill_spend.Value, "Skills")
```

My problem is however that I get an error saying that `skill_name` is missing its `dataset`, which doesn't make sense to me as it is informed in the end of the expression (`skills`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the purpose of `Lookup` and how it is used.  The purpose of the `Lookup` function is akin to a `JOIN` in SQL in some ways.  Basically, you would have two datasets that each have a matching field with the other.  In that scenario, the expression would match on the `skill_name` field and lookup the `skill_spend` value and the expression would look something like the following.

```
=Lookup(Fields!skill_name.Value, Fields!skill_name.Value, Fields!skill_spend.Value, "Skills")
```

As the [documentation shows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function?view=sql-server-2017), the first reference to `skill_name` is the field you are referencing from the current dataset.  The second reference is to the dataset from which you are attempting to look up a value.  The third expression is the field you are looking up and the dataset should be the one you are attempting to look up a value from, not the current dataset scope.

> ```
> Lookup(source_expression, destination_expression, result_expression, dataset)
> ```

From the best I can tell, you have a single dataset but separate textboxes that need the correct spend value.  I think the following expression will work.

```
= IIF(Fields!skill_name.Value = "First Aid", Fields!skill_spend.Value, Nothing)
```

This expression should get the `skill_spend` value associated with the row "First Aid" only and leave the textbox blank otherwise.